# Is there a way to get full-resolution contact photos on Android

Tags: android

Is there a way to get photos from the Android contact list in full resolution?

I've tried with the loadContactPhoto method but that returns a 50x50px image. 
I've tried querying the Contacts.Photos contentprovider and convert the Photos.DATA blob to a bitmap but that returns a 96x96px image.

I'm using SDK1.5 because I would like my app to support 1.5 devices